# Burned PSU possibly damaged hardware

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

My PSU recently burned out, I don't know if other hardware was affected is it safe to buy a new PSU and use my PC as I normally do?

How do I check for potential damages?
CPU: i7 2700K 3.5GHz
GPU: EVGA GTX 660 TI 3GB
PSU: Corsair GS800
RAM: Corsair Vengeance 2x4GB 1866MHz
Motherboard: ASRock P67 Extreme Gen4
HDD: Seagate 1TB

Comment: Do you mean, "if other HARDWARE" was affected?

Comment: There is no possible way for us to know or even help you determine if there was other damage until you install the new PSU

Answer (score 1):

So long as your new power supply is at least as powerful as your old, it should work. Provided you haven't burned out any of your existing hardware.

The standard way to tell if you have burnt out any of your existing hardware is to try it with a replacement power supply. It is very possible that you have damaged one or more of your existing components, but you might be lucky and your old power supply may have failed in a way that left everything else intact.

Comment: How would I go by finding out if different parts has been affected? Like if the PC runs fine, other hardware could still be damaged? Any software you can use for that purpose?

Comment: If your PC runs fine, the hardware is undamaged. Software won't help; if, say, your motherboard or CPU or RAM is damaged, you won't be able to boot up the PC and so won't be able to run any software.

Comment: How about the Corsair CX750 is it a good PSU, can I go SLI with it and is it compatible with current hardware?

Comment: We don't do hardware (or software) recommendations at Superuser, sorry.

Comment: Where would I get that then? Assuming you can point me there. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Don't Worry If PSU is burned, it will not gonna effect the any Softwares, As Softwares are inside Harddrive.
and Buying new PSU will be good choice.

750 Watts PSU will be very good for the system requirements you have..

I am also using corsair 750 watts PSU and i have GTX 660 2GB Card.

750 will be more then enough...

-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=

If you meant about other hardware affecting cuz of burned PSU, than it would be hard to tell, but i also once had a power supply burned out but thankfully it didn't damaged any other thing..
So no possible way of knowing of if your PSU damaged the other hardwares, but don't worry about softwares.. ;)

Comment: Im not sure if the PSU got the necessary in/outputs could you confirm, and will I be able to upgrade my PC with more HDDs and SLI?

Comment: @AndréNope
Why negative rep??
Yes SLI depends on your Motherboard, If your Motherboard Supports the Nvidia SLI then Sure 750 watts power supply can support SLI of your cards..
But If you can afford go for bigger PSU, not that 750 wont be able to support but because that if you might want to add more HDD's and etc accessories like water cooler etc then bigger power supply i would recommend, but for current system specifications 750 is good.
If you find modular PSU, you dont have to worry about in/outputs. Modular PSU's are great.

Comment: I didn't negative rep you :/ thanks for your help

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan - You attempted to answer a question which from my perspective cannot be answered. The only way to know if something else was damaged is to simply find out if it works.  You state a great number of things but didn't really explain the fact there simply isn't anyway for us to predict what was damaged in the event that caused the PSU to burn out.  I personally don't find answers that only state an opinion to be very helpful.  For example if it was a lighting strike then its likely everything could have been damaged.

Answer (score -2):

You could run your system on a 550 gold rated PSU actually. 750 is overkill for your system. Make sure its gold rated and you shouldnt run into any issues.

Comment: the Corsair CX750 is only bronze rated. Throw in a few more dollars and get the HX750 if you are dead set on a Corsair branded PSU.     http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139010&cm_re=corsair_hx750-_-17-139-010-_-Product

Comment: HX750 is too expensive for me, but CX750 should be fine?

Comment: @AndréNope - We don't do hardware recommendations here at Superuser.